# Author Citations

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I'm working on a paper for a course and I found a citation style that closely mimics the one that the instructor wants us to use the only problem is that I need it to have a comma after the journal name. I am using the following style here - http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nar - does anyone know how to do so? This way I could avoid custom making my own citation style.

Comment: Does this article help you? Especially the last paragraph about the FUNCTION article. http://chenfuture.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/diy-your-bibtex-style-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify the `.bst` file to achieve the output you want.

Locate `nar.bst` one your computer, copy it to a location where LaTeX can find it and rename it to, say, `mynar.bst`.
Open `mynar.bst` and find `FUNCTION {article}` (in my version of the file it's in line 626).
After `journal emphasize "journal" output.check`, add `", " *`, so the function becomes

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.date "year" output.check % TDS move date to here
  new.block
%  format.title "title" output.check % TDS NO TITLES
%  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      ", " * % this is new
      format.vol.num.pages output
%      format.date "year" output.check % TDS move date
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

To use your modified style change `\bibliographystyle{nar}` to `\bibliographystyle{mynar}`.

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  year          = {1983},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher \& Co.},
  address       = {Townsville},
}
@article{testart1,
  author  = {Steven C. Ientist},
  title   = {Thrilling, Intelligent and True Limes of Erudition},
  journal = {Journal of Articles},
  volume  = {20},
  number  = {3},
  year    = {1935},
  pages   = {1--46},
}
@article{testart2,
  author  = {Steven C. Ientist},
  title   = {Title},
  journal = {Journal of Articles},
  volume  = {20},
  number  = {4},
  year    = {1935},
  pages   = {50--70},
}
@article{testart3,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  number        = {3},
  pages         = {1-5},
  year          = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{mynar}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

results in
[image]